# It's a string manipulation problem with JS. I cant figure out why the main test fails

Tags: javascript, string, testing

A string manipulation exercise that is failimg in the main test.

I tried to figure out if some character was missing or broken, but I can't figure out.

```
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
    let x = phrase.toLowerCase();
    let y = blacklist.toLowerCase();
    let z = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= blacklist.length-1; i++) {
        z = blacklist[i];
        if (x.lastIndexOf(z)) {
            return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The return value is -1 if not found. It is between 0 and length if found.

Comment: Please provide a some test cases for how the function should behave for better answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the tests you'd run on this because the screenshot isn't in English but I can tell from the code snippet your equality check has a logic error.

`lastIndexOf()` returns a number (i.e., the index of the character in the string) or `-1` if not found in the string. `-1` is a truthy value so it will not return `false` if the value is not found. Everything but `0` will return false in your function.

I believe you are trying to return `false` if the character is found in the string, in that case you can change your equality to be:

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
    let x = phrase.toLowerCase();
    let y = blacklist.toLowerCase();
    let z = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= blacklist.length-1; i++) {
        z = blacklist[i];
        if (x.lastIndexOf(z) > -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any letter of the blacklist exists in the phrase, it should return false. If that's not you case then change the condition to x.lastIndexOf(z)==-1

```
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
        let x = phrase.toLowerCase();
        let y = blacklist.toLowerCase();
        let z = '';
        for (let i = 0; i <= blacklist.length-1; i++) {
            z = blacklist[i];
            if (x.lastIndexOf(z)!=-1) {
                return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) is `-1` if not found. It is between 0 and length if found.

I changed your code from `if (x.lastIndexOf(z))` to `if (x.lastIndexOf(z) >= 0)`.

By the way, I don't like the name `hasNoneLetters`. In my opinion it's better to test if the string has any of the forbidden characters, and do the negation in the calling code: `if (!hasLetters(phrase, blacklist))`. This way the function can also be used when making sure the phase has at least one of the characters.

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  let x = phrase.toLowerCase();
  let y = blacklist.toLowerCase();
  let z = '';
  for (let i = 0; i <= blacklist.length - 1; i++) {
    z = blacklist[i];
    if (x.lastIndexOf(z) >= 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

run.onclick = () => result.textContent = hasNoneLetters(phrase.value, blacklist.value)
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10ch;
}
```

```html
<h1>hasNoneLetters</h1>
<p>Returns <b>false</b> if the phrase has any of the characters in blacklist</p>
<label><span>Phrase</span><input id="phrase" value="Mate Academy"></label>
<label><span>Blacklist</span><input id="blacklist" value="pqrs"></label>

<label><span>Result</span><output id="result"></label>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

I created a `hasLetters`, that converts the phrase into an array, and then uses the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)-method to iterate over the list values.

```js
function hasLetters(phrase, list) {
  const x = phrase.toLowerCase();
  return Array.from( list.toLowerCase())
    .some( (d) => ~x.indexOf(d) )
}

run.onclick = () => result.textContent = hasLetters(phrase.value, list.value)
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10ch;
}
```

```html
<h1>hasLetters</h1>
<p>Returns <b>true</b> if the phrase has any of the characters in list</p>
<label><span>Phrase</span><input id="phrase" value="Mate Academy"></label>
<label><span>List</span><input id="list" value="pqrs"></label>

<label><span>Result</span><output id="result"></label>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a shorter script doing basically the same:

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  let x = phrase.toLowerCase(), res=false;
  blacklist.toLowerCase().split("").every(x=>res=!phrase.includes(x))
  return res;
}

// run a few tests:
const texts=["Hello everyone, I hope you are fine!","Good morning","Take care"],
      bl="false";
texts.forEach(t=>
  console.log(t,hasNoneLetters(t,bl))
)
```

So far it does not take care of Umlauts, minuscles and maiuscles (letter variations found in the UTF character sets).

Using `.every()` is similar to having an `if (...) return` in a `for` loop.